# Is there a way to add "distinct" to SSMS IntelliSense?

Tags: ssms, intellisense

For the last few versions of SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio), I have noticed that IntelliSense does not contain the word `distinct`.  Is there a way I can add this to the IntelliSense word bank?

The only instructions for [configuring IntelliSense](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173743.aspx) I could find had no options for adding to the word bank.

Is there an undocumented means to do this? While not critical to my productivity, it is something I would like to correct.

Comment: SSMS intellisense is fickle at best. There are a couple of 3rd party extensions that can significantly improve this... probably not worth the effort if you're just trying to skip the word `distinct` though.

Comment: Probably right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't believe there is any way to manipulate the IntelliSense dictionary. And you'll notice other T-SQL keywords are missing from the list, too:

```
SELECT
DELETE
INSERT
FROM
GROUP
ORDER
JOIN
WHERE
HAVING
```

`UPDATE` is there, but only because it is overloaded (a function you can use inside a trigger to see if a specific column was updated).

Further, I'd have to wonder what is wrong with your data model that you're typing `DISTINCT` enough where auto-complete will have any impact on your productivity at all. `DISTINCT` really should be rarely used; almost every time I see it in a query, it's being used to remove duplicates caused by bad design or bad join logic.

Comment: " by bad design or bad join logic" -- While I agree with you in principle, I am forced to work with the data I have, the customers I have, and the queries they are paying me to produce.

Comment: @Rubix_Revenge Understood, but that doesn't make them not bad.